# Aggregate columns with same date (sum)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx, xlsxwriter

So, i need to aggregate rows where the date is the same.

My code, as of now, returns the following:

```
                      date  value  source
0  2018-04-08 15:52:26.110      1  ANAPRO
1  2018-04-22 12:14:38.807      1  ANAPRO
2  2018-04-22 12:34:18.403      1  ANAPRO
3  2018-04-22 12:40:35.877      1  ANAPRO
4  2018-04-22 12:53:57.897      1  ANAPRO
5  2018-04-22 13:02:45.180      1  ANAPRO
6  2018-05-04 17:41:15.840      1  ANAPRO
7  2018-04-22 15:03:54.353      1  ANAPRO
8  2018-04-22 15:24:27.030      1  ANAPRO
9  2018-04-22 15:27:56.813      1  ANAPRO
```

I don't think I can aggregate the columns while I have HH:MM:SS.ms being showed alongside the date (I only need the date)

I've tried this :

```
df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b %d %Y.%f').astype(str)
```

But to no avail, I still got the same return.

The code is:

Reads the my excel file (user input).

```
df = pandas.read_excel(var + '.xlsx')
```

Selects the columns I need, and create a new .xlsx to contain it.

```
df = df.iloc[:, 36].to_excel(var + '_.xlsx', index=False)
```

Opens the new .xlsx file.

```
df = pandas.read_excel(var + '_.xlsx')
```

Renames the column

```
df = df.rename(columns={'Prospect Dt. Cadastro': 'date'})
```

Adds the other columns I need.

```
df['value'] = 1
df['source'] = 'ANAPRO'
```

Tries to format the date.

```
df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b %d` %Y.%f').astype(str)
```

Creates the final xlsx, with all the formatted data.

```
df = df.to_excel('payload.xlsx')
```

Reads the final xlsx.

```
df = pandas.read_excel('payload.xlsx', names=['date', 'value', 'source'])
```

Prints the first 10 rows.

```
print(df.head(10))
```

I'm new to python, so sorry if I'm doing something awkward, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you might want [`pandas.Series.dt.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date

>>> df
         date  value  source
0  2018-04-08      1  ANAPRO
1  2018-04-22      1  ANAPRO
2  2018-04-22      1  ANAPRO
3  2018-04-22      1  ANAPRO
4  2018-04-22      1  ANAPRO
5  2018-04-22      1  ANAPRO
6  2018-05-04      1  ANAPRO
7  2018-04-22      1  ANAPRO
8  2018-04-22      1  ANAPRO
9  2018-04-22      1  ANAPRO
```

Or, if your goal is aggregation using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html), you can retain all the information in your original date column, and group by only the date as such:

```
df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'])

df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date)
# for example, to get the sum each day:
# df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date).sum()

#             value
# date             
# 2018-04-08      1
# 2018-04-22      8
# 2018-05-04      1
```

Or, using [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'])

df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='D'))
```

Comment: `df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date`

Worked like a charm, but 

`df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date).sum()`

Didn't, still getting the same return as before, but with the formatted date.

Comment: Did you try the `groupby` *after* you modified `df['date']`? If so, you need to omit the `.dt.date`, and try `df.groupby('date').sum()`

Comment: Yep, got an error `Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 3 elements`

Comment: hmm, that's not happening for me, with your example dataframe... I'm getting the expected sums per day (I just added my output to my answer)

Comment: Hold on... are you trying to modify the value in the `value` column to be the sum of values on that day? Or what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: that's really strange! When I try like this `df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'].dt.date)
        df.groupby(df['date']).sum()`
I get the right date format, but without any aggregation.

When I try like this: `df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'])
        df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date).sum()`
the date isn't formatted anymore and still no aggregation is applied :(

Comment: that's exactly what i'm trying to do, sum the values (all are 1) that have the same day on the date column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171174/discussion-between-sacul-and-gabriel-fernandes).